# i have continuous ajax call how can i construct a table with the returned data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm in a situation where i get data from `server_side` in every `1 minute` my

question is how can i construct a table with the returned data?

i'm trying something like this but not working.

```
 <div id="table"></div>  <!-- my html -->


    var something = "abc";

function callEveryMin(){
         $.ajax({           
                url:"test.php",
               type:"POST",
               dataType:"json",
               data:{something:something},
               async: false,
               success: function(data){
                   var array = data.list;
                   console.log(array);
                   var table = '<table><tr><th> list value </th></tr>';
                   for(var i = 0; i<array.length;i++)
                   {
                        table += '<tr><td>'+array[i]+'</td></tr>';
                   }
                   table +='</table>';
                   $('#table').append(table);

              }
          });

}

// call the above function every minute

setTimeout(callEveryMin,60000);
```

**my php will be like this (test.php)**

```
echo json_encode(array("list" => ['a','b','c']));  // first run
```

and on second run like this

```
echo json_encode(array("list" => ['e','f','g']));  // second run
```

so on ......

my question is how can i append new `<td>...</td>` on every `sucessive ajax call`

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: you want to append `<td>` only or also the `<tr>`?

Comment: What is your `$('#table')` element ? Is it a div or table? Show your html pls.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac, `<tr><td>..</td></tr>`  ie both

Comment: create div and append the contentes with that div you will get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
<div id="table"></div>  <!-- my html -->


    var something = "abc";

function callEveryMin(){
         $.ajax({           
                url:"test.php",
               type:"POST",
               dataType:"json",
               data:{something:something},
               async: false,
               success: function(data){
                   var array = data.list;
                   console.log(array);
                   var table = ($('#table').html() == '')?'<table><tr><th> list value </th> </tr>':'';//if #table don't have a data inside it then add this else add empty
                   for(var i = 0; i<array.length;i++)
                   {
                        table += '<tr><td>'+array[i]+' </td></tr> ';
                   }
                   table +=($('#table').html() == '')?'</table>':'';//if #table don't have a data inside it then add this else add empty
                   $('#table').append(table);

              }
          });

}

// call the above function every minute

setTimeout(callEveryMin,60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var something = "abc";
var firstCall = false;
var table = '';
function callEveryMin(){
         $.ajax({           
                url:"test.php",
               type:"POST",
               dataType:"json",
               data:{something:something},
               async: false,
               success: function(data){
                   var array = data.list;
                   console.log(array);
                   if(!firstCall){
                      table += '<table><tr><th> list value </th></tr>';
                      firstCall = true;
                   }

                   for(var i = 0; i<array.length;i++)
                   {
                        table += '<tr><td>'+array[i]+'</td></tr>';
                   }
                   table +='</table>';
                   $('#table').append(table);

              }
          });

}
```

Assuming that your ajax data sends only refreshed values and not old values again.